# How to know what Activity has started the current Activity

Tags: android

How can I know what Activity has started the current Activity? Is there any specific method like, i.e. `getIntent().getCallerActivity()` or the only way is saving some information within the Intent using `putExtra()`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [getCallingActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29) which you can use to get the name of the calling activity if you started the sub-activity with [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29).